# Wrong mapping, cant find mistake

Tags: java, spring

This one part of code give me list of students, this is `Student` controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listStudents(Model theModel) {

        List<Student> theStudent = studentService.listStudent();

        theModel.addAttribute("students", theStudent);


        return "list-student";
    }
```

This one give me form for add new student, this is `Student` controller class:

```
@GetMapping("/showFormForAddNewStudent")
public String showFormForAddNewStudent(Model theModel) {

    Student theStudent = new Student();

    theModel.addAttribute("student", theStudent);

    return "add-student-form";

}
```

This one give me form to add new student, this is `Student` controller class:

```
@PostMapping("/addNewStudent")
public String addNewStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student theStudent) {

    studentService.addNewStudent(theStudent);

    return "redirect:/student/list";

}
```

I have this line of code in my `list-student.jsp`:

```
<input type="button" value="Add new student"
   onclick="window.location.href='showFormForAddNewStudent'; return false;">
```

And this is part of code for add student:

```
<form:form action="addNewStudent" method="POST" modelAttribute="student">
```

What is problem. When I run application and go to page for adding new student, browser open me this link `/student/list/showFormForAddNewStudent` instead of `/student/showFormForAddStudent`

I have same code for class `Instructor` and that work fine but with student wont.

This is code for my  `Instructor` class where everything works fine:

`list-instructor.jsp` part of main code:

```
<input type="button" value="Add new instructor"
       onclick="window.location.href='showFormForAddNewInstructor'; return false;">
```

`Instructor controller`:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/instructor")
public class InstructorController {

    @Autowired
    InstructorService instructorService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listInstructors(Model theModel) {

        List<Instructor> theInstructor = instructorService.listInstructors();

        theModel.addAttribute("instructors", theInstructor);


        return "list-instructor";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormForAddNewInstructor")
    public String showFormForAddNewInstructor(Model theModel) {

        Instructor theInstructor = new Instructor();

        theModel.addAttribute("instructor", theInstructor);

        return "add-instructor-form";

    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewInstructor")
    public String addNewInstructor(@ModelAttribute("instructor") Instructor theInstructor) {

        instructorService.addNewInstructor(theInstructor);

        return "redirect:/instructor/list";

    }
```

So, when I try to open `showFormForAddNewInstructor` from page `/instructor/list` that works fine and its open like this: `instructor/showFormForAddNewInstructor`

But when I try to open `/showFormForAddNewStudent` from page `/student/list` new page is 404 not found and url is `/student/list/showForForAddNewStudent` instead of `/student/showFormForAddNewStudent` like I put in mappings.

Comment: what are you using spring mvc or spring boot?

Comment: im using spring mvc. that `@GetMapping` works fine when I manually delete `/list` from URL, just dont know why is that `list` there when its not supposed to be

Comment: it is because when you go to /student/list as an url , the url navigation after that gets added to the url like /student/showForAddStudent. You have to use different approach.

Comment: can you help me? i have exactly the same code only with other variable names and i don't have this problem when calling url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<input type="button" value="Add new student"
   onclick="window.location.href='showFormForAddNewStudent'; return false;">
```

Use this:

```
<form:form method = "GET" action = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showFormForAddNewStudent">
      <input type="submit" value="Add new student">
</form:form>
```

Explanation why your code doesn't work:

Lets say you have an url: `/student/edit/1`.

In that same page if you have anchor tag like this

`<a href="/addStudentForm">Go to Add Student</a>`

the url for the href tag will be updated to

`localhost:8080/student/edit/addStudentForm`

if you want to move along with the context just add

`<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudentForm">Go to Add Student</a>`

which will than uses the context and updates the href to `localhost:8080/addStudentForm`

Comment: 404 not found. I have the same methods only with other access addresses, for example here is `/ student / list` while in the other controller is` / instructor / list` and so on and everything works normally

Comment: Use it according to your url in controller 
<form:form method = "GET" action = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/student/showFormForAddNewStudent">
      <input type="submit" value="Add new student">
</form:form>

Comment: But it's still not clear to me why he won't work the previous way. I repeat, this is just a copy of all the classes, those previous classes work great and the url is good for everyone.

Comment: can you update your question with instructor/list example so that i can update my answer as well

Comment: I did it. Really dont know,,,,,

Comment: that shouldn't work on others as well if it doesn't work on student. See the loaded url on both instructor and student page and remember my answer. I hope you will find it that way

Comment: idk, so frustrating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231859/discussion-between-bishal-gautam-and-stefan-jankovic).